# Zend Mail - Where to instantiate it?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm using a Data Mapper / Gateway design pattern.

So I have a:

Mapper;
Gateway;
Domain Object (mainly with getters and setters);
A controller;
A view.

My question is: where should I instantiate the Zend Mail ? 
I believe the view is obviously out of question, and the gateway is, as well, not to be considered.

The controller should be kept clean, so:

Mapper our Domain Object ?

If our form will have some select box that will retrieve data from the database, then, perhaps the Mapper will be the most appropriate place to instantiate Zend Mail ?

Thanks

Comment: I notice that we don't have yet a standard way for accomplish it. I liked the service idea but, naturally I tend to avoid services myself. I also struggle to put code inside controllers, and since it seems that there isn't one single solution, perhaps the best way to figure this out is to keep coding and see how it fit’s best. I will mark both of your questions as useful, but I can't mark them as an answer, because I haven't found one that satisfies and justifies itself entirely. This may be because, it really depends on the nature of our send mail task. Again, code will tell. Thank you both.

Comment: Yep, I do mailing either in the controller (like @Perfection) or pushed down into a service (like @Jerry Saravia). Never in a mapper or repository.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm? Well with Zend you can configure your Zend_Mail in your bootstrap or by using the application.ini file or some other config file. That's how I configure mine right now. For dev, I'll write the mails to a file and for testing I'll do mail over an actual mail server.

I instantiate my Zend_Mail instance in a class that I call Mail_Service. This mail service class will create a Zend_Mail instance internally when it needs to send a mail and will use an existing Zend_Mail instance if one has been created and more mails need to be sent.

It has methods that will send predefined mails for me. For example,

```
Mail_Service->sendWelcomeEmail( $userInfo )
```

OR

```
Mail_Service->sendActivationEmail( $userInfo )
```

Say for example my controller gets a request to create a new user, then the over all flow of my code will be like this

```
//in the controller
//process form from browser somehow

UserAccountService->createNewUser( $userInfo );



/////////////////
/// Within the user account service

public function createNewUser( $userInfo )
{
    $userMapper->createNewUser( $userInfo );
    $preferencesMapper->createDefaultPreferencesForUser( $userInfo );

    MailService->sendWelcomeEmail( $userInfo );
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but this way my service have function
names that are relevant to the service and capture a whole work flow instead of being atomic operations that just forward calls to other objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But do you need to compose your email somehow no? Like: "username", "user password" and send it to the email as well. Those data will come from the a data source. Is that userInfo an array or an object, and then you split the information on it inside "sendWelcomeEmail" for example ?

Comment: Hey, UserInfo is just an object with simple string properties like you say. Inside the mail service, I use a Zend_View object to 'render' a .php file in my email templates folder. I take the rendered string and use it as the text for the email. 

I create the Zend_View object used for rendering in the MailService but you can also just pull it from the FrontController as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always keep code that sends mail in my controllers.

Model - database/business logic

View  - html / presentation layer

Controller - The code that does stuff.